# Can't deploy android application on panasonic toughpad fz-a1 from eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm developing an Adroid application (v.14) with Eclipse and I want to deploy it on Panasonic FZ-A1 toughpad. When I try to deploy the app Eclipse shows me the active devices list, but the tablet didn't appear in it. I setted true the Debug USB option on toughpad, but nothing goes right. Is there any step that I have undone, or I actually ignore (for example installing drivers for Windows 8.1)? Consider that Windows 8.1 is able to synchronize with tablet.

Comment: Have you installed the usb drivers? `<<android-sdk-windows>>\extras\google\usb_driver`

Comment: No, I've forgotten it. Now, with drivers,  it works. Thank you